# Eclipse Oxygen Window Builder Error with Java SE 10.0.1

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder, java-10

I am using Eclipse Oxygen .3a and using compliance with JDK Java SE-10.0.1 I am trying to use windows builder which worked with Oxygen and Java SE-9 on another computer, however, I can not get the IDE to open the "Design" tab. with this setup... I am also running JDK SE10

When I click on the design tab I get the following error:

**Eclipse is running under 0, but this Java project has a 9 Java compliance level, so WindowBuilder will not be able to load classes from this project. Use a lower level of Java for the project, or run Eclipse using a newer Java version.**

I cant use a newer version of eclipse as I dont see anything out there. I've tried setting the compliance level to Java SE-9 with no change in operation (even opened and closed to get the same result). I was looking to see if I could download Java SE-9 again but I only see Java SE-10.0.1 out there for download. Can Java SE-9 still be acquired?

Another note I tried opening a **new** project with compliance set at Java SE 10 and I get the same results. Does anyone have any ideas on what else I could try?

Thank you

Comment: Java 9 downloads may be obtained here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase9-3934878.html (they are in the Archive downloads from the Oracle site).

Comment: Went back to 9.0.4 and used Eclipse Oxygen.3a  EE IDE and that works, I will stay away from 10.0.1 until I have no other choice. Thanks for the link!!

Comment: It looks like another user faced a similar problem with WindowsBuilder: [Eclipse is running under 0, but this Java project has a 9 Java](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1093032/). It's good that you have resolved your problem, but just to be clear this is not an issue with Java 10 per se; rather it seems to be an issue when using WindowBuilder with Java 10.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Eclipse photon and usually get this problem when i try to switch to windowBuilder. I have installed both Java JDK 1.8 and Java 10 in my PC and this how i fix this:

1. Open your project
2. Right click on JRE System Library [Java SE-10]
3. Click on Properties
4. On the next window, change to Java SE-1.8 in the Execution environment comboBox
5. Apply and close
6. Retry to open project with windowBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had an issue with the program I was writing that was difficult to debug when I realized that I had a JDK update! So I went to JDK 10.0.1 and had the same exact issue you described above. Perhaps Windowbuilder hasn't been updated to be compatible with 10.0.1 yet.

9.0.1 works great for me on Windows 10, though I may try 9.0.4
Here is a link to the archived versions.

http://jdk.java.net/archive/

Uninstall 10.0.1 then unpack the compressed file to the correct location (program files\Java) (program files(x86)\Java) whichever you're using.

Answer (score -1):

I'd like to add - dear people, notice that you should use not just *Eclipse Oxygen 3.a*, but just right  [**Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers**](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/oxygen3a). [(*link for Oxygen)*](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/oxygen3a)

It is important that you install the JDK and Oxygen IDE of the same architecture (both must be x86 or x64).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I would suggest that next time, you add such things as a comment on the post, not as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. I wanted to post a comment, but got message "not enough reputation".

Comment: I'm glad you're excited about participating, and I hope you have a really great experience on the site. I hope to see many more great comments and answers! You'll go far!