# Java swing on eclipse oxygen 4.7.3a?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, windowbuilder

I am trying to use windowbuilder on eclipse oxygen 4.7.3a on macOS highSierra. it installed fine but every time I try to open the design part it displays this error

> Eclipse is running under 0, but this Java project has a 1.8 Java
>   compliance level, so WindowBuilder will not be able to load classes
>   from this project. Use a lower level of Java for the project, or run
>   Eclipse using a newer Java version.

I tried everything. like changing the running enviroment, .jre files, try different JDE. nothing working. any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like you are probably using Java 10 and windowbuild doesn't understand the version number for Jaa 10.

Comment: so what solutions I have?

Answer (score 1):

Your only short term solution is to use a Java version <= 9.

Initially WindowBuilder did not work with Java 9 for several reasons. See 
[Bug 526098 - WindowBuilder fails to work on Java 9](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=526098).

One of those issues was that the the System Property **java.version** was unexpectedly just "9":

> Please check that you have exactly 9.0 JDK, it worked for me with
>   9.0.1 until I downgraded target JRE to 9.0, which has unusual `System.getProperty("java.version").equals("9")`

The fixes to get WindowsBuilder working on Java 9 were only completed on 2/21/18, and based on your error it looks like a similar issue exists when running WindowsBuilder using Java 10. I suggest you [create a Bug Report with Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=EPP).

See also:

- SO Post [Eclipse Oxygen Window Builder Error with Java SE 10.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50124714/eclipse-oxygen-window-builder-error-with-java-se-10-0-1) where the solution/workaround was to regress to Java 9.
- This [Eclipse Forum post](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1093118/) where a user is reporting a similar problem to yours.

Answer (score 1):

#### Uninstall Java Version and Install lower version of Java(8).Support for WindowBuilder is not provided anymore.

**How to uninstall current version?(Mac)**

Go to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/ to see current version of java and replace jdk1.8.0_131.jdk with yours.

1. sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk
2. sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane
3. sudo rm -rf /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
4. sudo rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Oracle/Java

**Install Java 8**:

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Then:
Right click on your project and go to Properties
[image]

Make sure your configuration look like this,
At the top of picture Configure Workspace settings click on it  (Uncheck project specification settings) and then see image below
[image: Figure1]

Apply same as in picture Then enable "project specification settings"

Restart Your Eclipse

Done!!