# Eclipse Window Builder error under Java 10

Tags: javascript, eclipse, windowbuilder

**Eclipse is running under 0, but this Java project has a 10 Java compliance level, so WindowBuilder will not be able to load classes from this project. Use a lower level of Java for the project, or run Eclipse using a newer Java version.**

That is the error I'm getting when I installed the window builder. I have made sure both Eclipse and the project are running the same versions yet it is still giving me that error.

Edit:

[proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TU7v9.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java swing on eclipse oxygen 4.7.3a?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50187896/java-swing-on-eclipse-oxygen-4-7-3a/50225076#50225076) and/or [Eclipse Oxygen Window Builder Error with Java SE 10.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50124714/eclipse-oxygen-window-builder-error-with-java-se-10-0-1). It looks like WindowBuilder does not work using Java 10.

Comment: If it does not work using Java 10 and I cannot go back to 9 what do you suggest I do for a window builder.

Comment: @Yuki Why is it impossible to go back to Java 9? (Java 10 has only been available for 7 weeks!) Since other users are reporting the same problem with WindowBuilder as you with Java 10, I don't see that you have any other short term option.

Comment: I checked online for Java 9 and could not find a download for it and the JDK. T-T

Comment: Did this work with Java 9? My information is that windowbuilder does not work with Java 9 or 10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/50191328/2849346

Comment: @greg-449 Bug 526098 is [RESOLVED FIXED for WindowBuilder not working on Java 9](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=526098). And [another SO poster reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50124714/eclipse-oxygen-window-builder-error-with-java-se-10-0-1) that "_Went back to 9.0.4 and used Eclipse Oxygen.3a EE IDE and that works_".

Comment: @Yuki Use this link to download JDK9: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase9-3934878.html

Comment: Thank you I will try that when I get home tonight!

Comment: Do I need to make sure I'm using old Eclipse as well to make sure?

Comment: @Yuki Use Eclipse version Oxygen.3a  with JDK 9.

Answer (score 1):

A MORE SIMPLE SOLUTION: This problem was giving me some difficulty and I hated the hassle of rolling back to a previous version of java to fix it.

There were some developers that workshopped an alternative solution that involved using the install new software function and updating the version of WB via this function. Worked beautifully. The solution is as follows

Wim Jongman CLA Friend 2018-06-06 11:31:54 EDT

...I just got a report back from a user that tells me that upgrading to WB 19.2. helped to solve this issue for him:

Check the installing new software link from [1]
Use the update site from [2]
Select to install everything except stuff that requires WDP

[1] http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-129.htm&cp=0_3_17

[2] http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/integration/4.8/

Answer (score 0):

Solution FOUND

Drop down to Java 9 and make sure to have 3.a Eclipse and you are good! 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase9-3934878.html
There is a link to get Java 9.

Thank you, Everyone, that helped!!

Comment: I have exactly this version of Eclipse and java 9 and _not_ working - precisely the reason that brought me here.

Answer (score 0):

This problem may still occur with  WindwowBuilder 1.9.2 and JDK 11 and may be the result of Eclipse itself being launched with an older Java virtual machine.

To solve it, first verify that Project JDK compliance is 11 (Project..Java Compiler..JDK Compliance), and that Java Build Path (Project..Build Path..Libraries) is set to JavaSE-11 (Both settings can also be configured as default for all projects in Window..Preferences..Java..Compiler and Java..InstalledJREs..ExecutionEnvironment).

If that does not solve the problem, then go to 
Help..About Eclipse IDE..Installation Details..Configuration 
and check the -vm entry to make sure that Eclipse is started with JDK 11.
On Windows the -vm property may be set to something like: 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.4\bin\server\jvm.dll

If the configuration's -vm entry points to a lower Java version, then close Eclipse and launch it from the command line by appending ('-vm "path-to-JDK11\bin\server\jvm.dll"). You can also check the eclipse.ini file for the -vm entry (or add the -vm entry to the eclipse.ini file).

Answer (score 0):

Solution is very simple .Just go to build path and remove jre if it higher than 8 (9 may also work but i have tested with 8 version) and add jre version 8 by clicking

> add library -> add jre system library.

please not you need to install jdk 8 first.